# Android Fabric crashlytics issue

Tags: android, crashlytics, google-fabric

After adding the fabric crashlytics i'm getting error as no class definition found error for MultiPartBuildEntry in android 4.4

```
 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartEntityBuilder
 at clovewearable.commons.social.server.SignUpService.generateMultiPartPayload(SignUpService.java:171)
 at clovewearable.commons.social.server.SignUpService.triggerAPICall(SignUpService.java:110)
 at clovewearable.commons.social.ui.SignUpFragment.triggerAPICall(SignUpFragment.java:585)
 at clovewearable.commons.social.ui.SignUpFragment.validateNormalSignIn(SignUpFragment.java:388)
 at clovewearable.commons.social.ui.SignUpFragment.onClick(SignUpFragment.java:427)
 at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4640)
 at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19421)
 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5476)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084)
 at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: your application extends MultiDexApplication?

Comment: No i'm not extending coz i'm using third party sdk so i'm extending their application class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your `Application.class` should be extended from `MultiDexApplication`

For that you should add such code in you gradle

```
android {
defaultConfig {
...
   multiDexEnabled true
}  
dependencies {
...
   compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.2'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To initialize the fabric inside a class we have to start the fabric catalyst.

Use the following line inside `onCreate` to initialize fabric:

```
Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics());
```

Comment: You have to do it in every class where ever you are going to use it at least that is what i know....  Try doing it in every class

Comment: its not crashing for fabric its crashing in the apache mime library adding fabric is effecting to the apache library

Comment: Your logcat specifies all the class names  that are not been initialize

Comment: No its initialized if remove fabric part it works perfectly

Comment: have you added dependecy correctly???    

    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.8@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }

Comment: compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.3.1'
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.3.2'
    compile 'no.nordicsemi.android.support.v18:scanner:1.0.0'
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.8@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }

Comment: And one more is its happening only in 4.4 rest all working fine

Comment: look what i did was initialize fabric in every class and not inside application class and it worked for me that is all i can tell for now

Comment: yes also try the mulitdex which is been stated bellow it may help the defaultConfig {
...
   multiDexEnabled true  }    inside your gradle file